# I have validation error for graphql query

Tags: graphql

My query

```
query MyQuery($resourceId: ID) {
  resource(id: resourceId) { name }
}
```

I have an error: Field "resourceId" argument "id requires type ID found ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying

```
query MyQuery($resourceId: ID) {
  resource(id: $resourceId) { name }
}
```